# What do we do about [web-conference], [conference] and [video-conferencing]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I've found a set of conference-related tags, here are the retags I have already did:

- Retagged 4 questions from [conferencing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conferencing) to [conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conference). [1](https://superuser.com/questions/315719/what-to-look-for-in-a-good-open-conference-microphone),  [2](https://superuser.com/questions/284866/can-a-polycom-phone-use-freeswitch-as-a-conference-server), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/280831/are-there-any-programs-open-source-ubuntu-pertaining-to-webinars), [4](https://superuser.com/questions/252828/best-way-to-have-video-conferencing)
- Retagged 2 questions from [teleconference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/teleconference) to [conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conference). [1](https://superuser.com/questions/194493/software-for-remote-whiteboard-that-works-on-linux-and-mac-osx), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/269575/polycom-for-both-analog-phone-computer)

So, killed the two smallest tag, we're now left with:

- 3 questions in [web-conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-conference) (Dunno if web makes it different, I'm only down to obvious retags)
- 19 questions in [conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conference)
- 22 questions in [video-conferencing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-conferencing)

But it seems to me that they are all trying to do the same thing, so I think we should put them under the same tag; be it either under [conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conference), [conferencing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conferencing) or [video-conferencing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-conferencing).

Comment: This is a _computer site_ so I don't think we need [video-conferencing].. and [conference] has the most tags of the remaining.. Who does the synonymizing around here? Does Trogdor or Clippy handle it?

Comment: @Raystafarian: Those questions are about problems where the computer comes into play, look through the tag's open questions to get an idea. Synonymizing happens by the community / moderators. Trogdor is only for burnination and Clippy is only there to annoy us, haven't seen him do actual work... :D

Comment: Right, I figure since it's a computer site every conference question has to do with the computer.. I guess there are conference calls vs video conferencing, but I just don't see the need to call it video or audio, conference should work fine here. And someone needs to get that lazy paperclip to _do something_ around here rather than just pop-in to taunt us..

Comment: I agree with @Raystafarian, let's just put them all into `conferencing`.

Comment: @slhck: Sounds good. So, we just need a moderator to set up some references to that...

Comment: The problems and use cases of audio conferences are different from those with video. It involves different hardware, possibly different software, etc. What's the reason for merging them into the less descriptive `conferencing`? Why not keep it split into audio-only and video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[web-conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-conference), [conference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conference) and [video-conferencing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-conferencing) are now merged into [conferencing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conferencing).